# IIS Express Folder rights

Tags: asp.net

I have created a Web application. i need to add 2 virtual directories. i have gone to the properties of the application and in the web tab i have created the 2 directories. i have the run the site and gone into the IIS express config and changed the physical path of the 2 directories. the directories are mapped from a server.

when i run the site i get "Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server."

how do i know which user is IIS express is using to know how to give access to the directories?

Thanks

Gareth

Comment: in the projec tproperties you can set the authemtication type; e.g windows, anonymous ...

Comment: Hi, thansk for the reply. we are not using a windows domain so Windows Authetication does not work for this

Comment: can you give more info on what you are using etc?